# How to make <table> fit to its parents height (not exceeded)

Tags: html, css

I need to create a table that will fill the whole width and height of its parent. The parents max-height is set to 220px which should not be exceeded by the table's content. The tbodys max-height is to 200px.

So far I have tried all kinds of answers that I could find, like setting the table to display block and defining the max-heights on different elements. None of all the suggestions helped.

The tables content is always exceeding the parent's height

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/0gj3v7ak/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>table max height</title>
    <style>
      #container {
        max-height: 220px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: green;
      }
      .tg {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        table-layout: fixed;
      }
      .tg tbody {
        overflow: auto;
        max-height: 200px;
      }
      .tg td {
        border-color: rgb(242 244 245);
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .tg th {
        background-color: rgb(242 244 245);
        border-color: rgb(242 244 245);
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <table class="tg">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
            <th>Position</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Coldplay</td>
            <td>195</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>a-ha</td>
            <td>194</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Pop Smoke</td>
            <td>193</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Topic</td>
            <td>192</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Drake</td>
            <td>191</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Roddy Ricch</td>
            <td>190</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Juice WRLD</td>
            <td>189</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Cochise</td>
            <td>188</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Pop Smoke</td>
            <td>187</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Ariana Grande</td>
            <td>186</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Jamie Miller</td>
            <td>185</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Sleepy Hallow</td>
            <td>184</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Regard</td>
            <td>183</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Lil Tjay</td>
            <td>182</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>table max height</title>
    <style>
      #container {
        max-height: 220px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: green;
        overflow:auto; //add overflow css
      }
      .tg {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        table-layout: fixed;
      }
      .tg tbody {
        overflow: auto;
        max-height: 200px;
      }
      .tg td {
        border-color: rgb(242 244 245);
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .tg th {
        background-color: rgb(242 244 245);
        border-color: rgb(242 244 245);
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <table class="tg">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
            <th>Position</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Coldplay</td>
            <td>195</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>a-ha</td>
            <td>194</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Pop Smoke</td>
            <td>193</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Topic</td>
            <td>192</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Drake</td>
            <td>191</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Roddy Ricch</td>
            <td>190</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Juice WRLD</td>
            <td>189</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Cochise</td>
            <td>188</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Pop Smoke</td>
            <td>187</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Ariana Grande</td>
            <td>186</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Jamie Miller</td>
            <td>185</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Sleepy Hallow</td>
            <td>184</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Regard</td>
            <td>183</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2021-07-17</td>
            <td>Lil Tjay</td>
            <td>182</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: overflow:auto; //add overflow css to div